# Laravel - Not returning to view after sending email

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function sendSubMail(Request $request){
    $data = ['text' => $request->input('message'), 'subject' => $request->input('subject')];
    $emails = DB::table('emails')->get();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($emails); $i++) { 
        Mail::to($emails[$i])->queue(new Newsletter($data));
    }
    return view('emailSent', ['sub' => 'Emails successfully sent']);
}
```

the emails are being sent but after sending its not returning to the specified view

Comment: Can you provide more context? How is that method called? Is it a controller action?

Comment: Yes it is from controller.It was running fine untill I used for loop

Comment: You say it's not returning to the view. What is it doing instead? White screen? If so can you inspect the page (F12 on Chrome) and check what the response status code is?

Comment: its not redirecting anywhere. but emails are being sent

Comment: That will return the view in `HTML`...but it sounds like you might be wanting a `redirect`? Try something like `return back()->with(['sub' => 'Emails successfully sent']);`.

Comment: It is not working

Comment: What is it doing instead? White screen? If so can you inspect the page (F12 on Chrome) and check what the response status code is?

Comment: emails are being sent and Its not redirecting anywhere.

Comment: Are you calling the `sendSubMail` method asynchronously (ie: `ajax`, `axios`, etc.)?

Comment: No, I'm posting a form. I'm Not using any ajax calls

Comment: Okay, then [redirect helper methods](https://laravel.com/docs/master/responses#redirects) are what you want and should be working. Depending on what method calls that `sendSubMail` you might need to move the `redirect` into another method...you'll want to `return` that from the method that you originally `post` to.

Comment: its solved. when email sending fails it was stopping. I added a try-catch.

Comment: Just FYI that will fail when that collection gets big enough...